# Were three brothers killed while trying to have sex with a crocodile?

Tags: africa

Someone shared [ZW (Zimbabwe) News article](https://zwnews.com/2016/12/08/news-from-mzansi-today/) on Facebook. I don't believe it is true.

According to the story, three brothers in Limpopo, South Africa attempted to rape a crocodile after being told it would improve their sex lives, but were killed by it.

> The quest to become bedroom warriors turned into a tragedy after a Limpopo family lost three sons in a crocodile attack. A family known for its bedroom curse of failing to perform when it matters most (during intercourse) fell in deadly jaws of the strongest reptile after a Sangoma gave them *muthi* and instructed them to go and rape a female crocodile.

A search for the story shows a few sources but they appear to be all pretty much copy & pastes of each other (suggesting just one source). The image has a play button superimposed on it, even though it isn't a video makes it even less credible.

But none of the links were to a debunking site like snopes.com. Also the link above also seems to report "straight" seeming news.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although that webpage had protection to avoid anyone easily copying their image, I was able to find it in the source code and do a reverse image search.

The earliest source I found for the image was [SAfrognews on Twitter](https://twitter.com/SAfrognews/status/786428228974108672) (October 12, 2016) - which predates the December 8, 2016 date on the ZW News article):

> BRAVE Limpopo men catch crocodile after chasing it all over the Levubu River

The image on Twitter doesn't have the non-fuctional play button super-imposed, and the man on the right isn't censored with pixelization.

---

The apparent origin of the "raping a crocodile" story also turned up in the reverse image search:

> **[Limpopo Brothers Gang RAPE crocodile that had been EATING their livestock](http://africannewsupdates.com/2016/10/19/limpopo-brothers-gang-rape-crocodile-eating-livestock/)**
>
> Fauxtire – 19th October 2016
>
> Four brothers and their cousins from Limpopo have been arrested after they captured a crocodile which had been eating their livestock and allegedly gang-ra_ped it for days.
>
> ...
>
> Reached for a comment one of the brothers who talked to iMzansi reporters said they didn’t see anything wrong in punishing the predator that had been preying on their livestock. ” We are not at all attracted to crocodiles or any animals for that matter. We just wanted our revenge, to punish her real hard,” he said without showing a single shred of remorse.

While the story is slightly different (nobody died, they did it as revenge), there is one key word here: "Fauxtire" - i.e. [fake satire](http://www.thatsfake.com/the-difference-between-satire-and-fauxtire/).

ZWNews appears to be ripping off this fake, satirical article, adding photograph from another source, and trying to pass it off as real news.